# How do I address 'Ensures elements with an ARIA role that require parent roles are contained by them' in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, accessibility

I've been tasked to address some accessibility issues in our React Native app and using axe-DevTools in Chrome, as well as, @axe-core/react. These can be pretty elusive sometimes when I think I'm addressing the issue but doesn't fix it. An example is

'Ensures elements with an ARIA role that require parent roles are contained by them'

So I'm guessing this means the parent divs? Of course since axe-DevTools is libary/framework agnostic, I have to translate that to React components. I am using `AccessibilityLabel` and `AccessibilityRole` to address issues.

So axe-Devtools is telling me this:

[image]

So this in html:

```
<div>
 <div>
 <li>
```

in React is:

```
<Card>
 <TouchableOpacity>
  <View>
```

I have tried to add `AccessibilityRole="menuitem"` just for starters in `<View>` or `<ToouchableOpacity>` parent divs but this doesn't seem to address the issue. How should I approach this? I don't have much experience with accessibility.

Comment: Your HTML—at least the part you shared—is invalid. You cannot use a `<li>` without `<ul>` or `<ol>`. The basics for accessibility is semantic HTML. So while your a11y validation fails due to pure role semantics, an HTML validation would fail for the same reason: These elements (ul, ol) carry the role `list` and will solve your issue.

Comment: To bring it back to React Native: It seems that the Card component renders as an `<li>`, e.g. listitem, so you will need a component that carries the list role, like CardList or something. Card does not seem to be a React Native component, which component library are you using?

Comment: <Card /> is a reusable custom component. I'm trying to understand how to make a parent component of <Card /> to be a <ul>.

Comment: Well where does that reusable component come from? Is it from a library or did you write it?

Comment: We wrote it. It's a custom component.

Answer (score 1):

The error concerns the wrapping element. [A `…item` role must be child of a `…list` role](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#scope), so you need a wrapper that has that role.

```
<ul>
  <Card>
   <TouchableOpacity>
    <View>
```

Should do the trick, if it’s the `<Card>` that will render as `<li>`.

If you want a more semantic approach, you could create a component for that.

```
const CardList = props => <ul>{props.children}</ul>;
```

Comment: Oh wow I didn't realize you can use <ul> in Native.